# Link User id to a session

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a program for a company that has 4 employees, how do I link the userid such that I will be able to tell which employee used the system at particular point in time

Comment: you might want to give more information. and also add code you already tried using

Answer (score -1):

You can use the os library.

Either use `os.getuid()` to get the user ID or `os.getlogin()` to get the username.
To get the time in a readable way you can use the `time.localtime()` function from the time library.

I don't know how your system work, but if it's only a program that you launch, write into a logfile each time with instruction at the beginin of your program.